# User answer a question but ask another question in the answer. What to do in those cases?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I have recently review a user which answer a late question. However, he answer but he ask another question in his answer. Are there any guidelines about how to treat those cases?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think the user is answering the question, and then asking another question, suggest an edit (or edit the answer when you have the privilege of editing any post) to remove the question in the answer.
If the user is really describing their cases, and then asking a different/related question, then the post should be flagged as "not an answer."